# Accessing parent form's listbox from child form

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create child form and access parent's listbox from it.

Parent form code:

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientCard f = new ClientCard();
        f.Owner = this;
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Child form code:

```
public ClientCard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainFormWindow main = this.Owner as MainFormWindow;
        this.mainForm = main;
    }

MainFormWindow mainForm;

private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {             
        textBoxName.Text = this.mainForm.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

Whenever i'm trying to use it i get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. Why i can't use it like this?

**UPDATE:**

Notice that the code will work fine if i will use it like this:

```
private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainFormWindow main = this.Owner as MainFormWindow;
        textBoxName.Text = main.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for advice, i placed breakpoint on a "buttonClick" and now i can see that mainForm is null. But i still dont understand why. How it can be null if i initialized it in child form constructor?

Comment: Yes, of course it is.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in buttonTest_Click and inspect the various objects?  That should tell you what's null pretty fast.

Comment: Is it possible that `TextBoxName` is not instantiated at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with your code. It appears that the `Owner` property is still `null` in the constructor.

```
MainFormWindow main = this.Owner as MainFormWindow;
```

So `mainForm` is `null` and `mainForm.listBox1` throws an exception.

You'll need to reference `this.Owner` from the button's click event, or set `this.mainForm` in the form's load event.

Comment: Thanks, but this error appears even if i try to use Convert.ToString() etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I need my child windows/forms to access the parent, I prefer to do it explicitly.

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientCard f = new ClientCard(this);
    f.ShowDialog();
}

public partial class ClientCard : Form
{
    private MainWindow MainWnd;

    public ClientCard(MainWindow Wnd)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainWnd = Wnd;
        }
}
```